# http2: header block logical equivalence to a single frame

Tags: http-headers, http2

From the [http2 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-4.3):

> Each header block is processed as a discrete unit.  Header blocks MUST
> be transmitted as a contiguous sequence of frames, with no interleaved
> frames of any other type or from any other stream. The last frame in a
> sequence of HEADERS or CONTINUATION frames has the END_HEADERS flag
> set.  The last frame in a sequence of PUSH_PROMISE or CONTINUATION
> frames has the END_HEADERS flag set. **This allows a header block to be
> logically equivalent to a single frame.**

I see how "transmitted as a contiguous sequence of frames, with no interleaved frames of any other type or from any other stream" enables "a header block to be logically equivalent to a single frame", but why is logical equivalence to a single frame so important as to veer from how the rest of http2 works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it important because the processing of a header block changes the state of the connection held by the HPACK context.

To process a sequence like:

`HEADERS[stream=3,end_headers=false]`,
`HEADERS[stream=5,end_headers=true]`,
`CONTINUATION[stream=3,end_headers=true]`

you would need to wait for the `CONTINUATION` frame to arrive before processing the `HEADERS` frame for `stream=5`.

Now, imagine a malicious client that *does not* send that `CONTINUATION` frame: it would have the ability to completely halt the processing of frames on the server and forcing the server to buffer all the arriving frames, waiting for the `CONTINUATION` frame - not good.

So to make things simple in the specification and the protocol, it was mandated that `CONTINUATION` frames *cannot* be interleaved, which is a special treatment with respect to all the other HTTP/2 frames that *can* be interleaved.